# Nested for looping alternating operators (without a condition statement)

Tags: python

I'm working through lessons in John Zelle's Python book. I got to Ch.3 ex 15, where he wants me to write a program the will.

**Input**
     The n of terms to sum up.
**Process**
     n = 4/1 - 4/3 + 4/5 - 4/7 + 4/9....
**Output**
     sum of n

I am not at the point where he teaches condition statement. So I assume he want us to use for loops to get this done. Can this be done without a condition statement?

```
  2 def main():
  3     n = eval(input("Enter the number of terms: "))
  4     sum =1
  5     term1 = 1
  6     term2 =1
  7 
  8     for j in range(1,n,1):
  9         term1 = 4 /j
 10         for i in range(j):
 11             # I was able to iterate through the first 4/1 -4/3 
 12             term2 = 4/(j+2) 
 13             term4 = -4/(j+2)
 14             
 15             
 16         term3 = term1 - term2
 17         term4 = term3 + term4
 18         print(term3, term4 ) #How to iterate for 4/5 + 4/7 -4/9..
 19 
 20  main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the approach I would take:

```
tot = 0
denominator_size=1
denominator_sign=1
for i in range(n):
    tot += 4/(denominator_sign*denominator_size)
    denominator_size += 2
    denominator_sign = denominator_sign * (-1)
print(tot)
```

The series you are adding up has 4 as the numerator, and a denominator that increases in size by 2, but alternates in sign. So I set up the denominator as two different variables multiplied together: denominator_size, which will just increase by 2 every cycle and starts at 1 (so 1,3,5,...), and denominator_sign, which starts at 1 and then is multiplied by -1 each cycle (so 1,-1,1,-1,...).

Using the variable sum is generally considered poor practice, because it's used by python as a key work to add up lists and stuff. So I changed the tracking variable to tot. I also initiated tot to 0 (your code showed sum=1 which i didn't understand).

Lastly, you don't need two nested loops. If you have two nested loops, it is like you are summing over a 2-dimensional array. Here, you're just adding up a 1-dimensional series.

Comment: Thank you, for clarifying this for me.